# Minimum sample size in binomial distribution

Tags: hypothesis-testing, distributions, binomial-distribution

I have $2$ binomial distributions, $B_1(100, 0.2)$ and $B_2(n, 0.15)$
taken before and after 'some' change in item selection.

What is the smallest sample of items $n$ that must be taken in order for the probability to be at least $0.95$ that the proportion of 'selected' items in the sample after the change will be equal or less than $0.15$?

My try for the solution (no idea if right or wrong) is:

$$\sigma=((0.2)(1 - 0.2))^{0.5}$$
$$Z=\frac{n^{0.5}(0.15 - 0.2)}{\sigma} \sim N(0,1)$$
$$P(Z\ge(n^{0.5} / -0,125))$$
$$\Phi\left(\frac{n^{0.5}}{ -0.125}\right) = \Phi(1.645)$$
$$n=173.18$$
Unfortunately I have no way to check it myself.
Thank you for any help.